# How to set ViewPager tab titles using a string resource instead of hardcoded strings

Tags: android, string, fragmentpageradapter

I'm new to Android & stack overflow - so apologies in advance if my question is stupid!

I have a simple app with four tabs using TabLayout/ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter. I can get the tab titles to display using hardcoded strings, but when I try to set them using string resources my code is returning the string's index values, instead of the actual strings, as per screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jolwW.png)

Here is the code for my FragmentPagerAdapter class:

```
package com.example.thisi.londonguide;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class AttractionFragPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    AttractionFragPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new RestaurantFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new MuseumFragment();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return new ParksFragment();
        } else return new HotelsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_1),String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_2),String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_3),String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_4)};


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        super.getPageTitle(position);
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to call something like `getResources().getString(R.string.mystring)` to get the actual string values

Comment: Thanks @John... I tried calling like this 'String.getResources().getString(R.string.tab_title_1)'  but I get this error "cannot resolve getResources()"

Answer (score 1):

you must just replace this line

```
 private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_1),String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_2),String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_3),String.valueOf(R.string.tab_title_4)};
```

with this line

```
 private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{getString(R.string.tab_title_1),getString(R.string.tab_title_2),getString(R.string.tab_title_3),getString(R.string.tab_title_4)};
```

or use

```
private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.tab_title_1),getResources().getString(R.string.tab_title_2),getResources().getString(R.string.tab_title_3),getResources().getString(R.string.tab_title_4)};
```

getString() need `context`

Answer (score 0):

You can get string from resource value by calling:
**getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.page1_title);**

and page1_title is the string value in the **string.xml** file:
title example

here is an example how to to add fragments to a ViewPagerAdapter with title:

private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {

```
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new viewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(Fragment1.newInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab1_title));
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment2.newInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab2_title));
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment3.newInstance(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab3_title));


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```